# python: цикл for выводит значения в произвольном порядке

Tags: python-3.x

ищу значения в файле и print выводит значения не по порядку - в чём причина?

```
with io.open('C:/test.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
for line in file:
    if x_1 in line:
        print('x_1      ' + line, end='')
    if x_2 in line:
        print('x_2      ' + line, end='')
    if x_3 in line:
        print('x_3      ' + line, end='')
    if x_4 in line:
        print('x_4      ' + line, end='')
    if x_5 in line:
        print('x_5      ' + line, end='')
    if x_6 in line:
        print('x_6      ' + line, end='')
    if x_7 in line:
        print('x_7      ' + line, end='')
    if x_8 in line:
        print('x_8      ' + line, end='')
    if x_9 in line:
        print('x_9      ' + line, end='')
    if x_10 in line:
        print('x_10      ' + line, end='')
```

Comment: В каком порядке находит, в том и выводит.

Comment: а как сделать чтоб выводил по возрастанию?

Comment: Как обычно - сортировать.

Comment: Вместо печати, добавлять в список. Список отсортировать и вывести. Как вариант...

Comment: А еще можно занаследовать `UserList`, во время добавления записи в свой список производить модификацию, а при выводе на печать списка - сортировать. Можно еще и сортировку кэшировать.

Comment: Посмотрите на мой исправленный ответ, думаю, что теперь все сделал как надо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так.

```py
with io.open('test.txt') as file:

    file = [line for line in file] # Содержимое файла переносим в список(без этого ошибка)

    for i in range(1, 99): # Тут можно указать хоть миллион, перебор прервется когда длинна списка станет равна 0
        remove_list = [] # Сюда запишутся значения которые выведутся на экран
        for line in file:
            result = re.match(f'x_{i}\s' , line) # Поиск x_.. в начале строки. ВАЖНО ЕСЛИ У ВАС НЕТ ПРОБЕЛА ПОСЛЕ Х_.., А СРАЗУ ТЕКСТ, ТО ЗАМЕНИТЕ \s НА \w
            if result is not None:
                print('x_{} - {}'.format(i, line), end='')
                remove_list.append(line)

        for value in remove_list: # Удаление значений которые уже выведены
            file.remove(value)

        if len(file) == 0: # Проверка длинны списка
            print('stoped!')
            break
```

Вот содержимое файла test.txt:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот вывод списка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь помог!!!

Comment: Вопрос не в выводе на экран, а о сортировке. См. комментарии. Тогда уж: `temp_list.sort() print(temp_list)`. Но и тут, из вопроса не вполне понятен критерий сортировки.

Comment: Все верно, поскольку не понятно как сортировать и что там будет (числа, строки и т.д.), то можно из file (он как список) с помощью операторов if проверяя по очереди все переменные x_... добавить их в список. И их порядок в списке будет таким же как порядок операторов if в коде. Так как сначала проверится условие 'if x_1 in file:' и если это истина, первым в списке будет x_1 и так далее.

Comment: этот код будет добавлять в список и печатать все x_ - если они в файле - а надо чтоб печатала строки которые содержат x_

Comment: и сейчас я не могу запихать ('x_7      ' + line, end='') из-за end=''   - в список все найденные значения для сортировки

Comment: А строки потом должны выводится с х_0 ...х_10 ...?

Comment: Посмотри мой ответ, я его переделал. Теперь все как нужно

Comment: спасибо но в файле уже 320 000 строк если file = [line for line in file] сделать думаю питону плохо будет)))

Comment: Да уж, ну и ситуация. Но в любом случае придется много раз перебрать содержимое файла. А имеются данные об максимальном значении x_ ?

Answer (score 1):

решил сделать так - да говнокод, но по другому не вижу вариантов строк содержащих например x_4 может быть несколько, очень не хотел так делать!

```
with io.open('C:/test.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        if x_1 in line:
            print('x_1      ' + line, end='')

with io.open('C:/test.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        if x_2 in line:
            print('x_2      ' + line, end='')

with io.open('C:/test.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        if x_3 in line:
            print('x_3      ' + line, end='')

with io.open('C:/test.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        if x_4 in line:
            print('x_4      ' + line, end='')

with io.open('C:/test.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        if x_5 in line:
            print('x_5      ' + line, end='')

with io.open('C:/test.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        if x_6 in line:
            print('x_6      ' + line, end='')

with io.open('C:/test.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        if x_7 in line:
            print('x_7      ' + line, end='')

with io.open('C:/test.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        if x_8 in line:
            print('x_8      ' + line, end='')

with io.open('C:/test.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        if x_9 in line:
            print('x_9      ' + line, end='')

with io.open('C:/test.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        if x_10 in line:
            print('x_10      ' + line, end='')
```

Comment: между открытиями файла запихал ещё пустую строку print() - для наглядности!

Comment: Совершенно незачем открывать и закрывать файл столько раз. Достаточно и одного, логика не пострадает. Ну а делать десять итераций, где достаточно одной, нерационально.

Comment: страдает логика я проверял - после поиска первого значения идёт остановка если опять не открыть файл

Comment: Значит не так проверял.

Comment: после открытия файла повторял for line in file:

Comment: Значит не так повторял. Наверняка второй цикл был уже не в блоке open, а вне его. Никаких ограничений на количество циклов нет.

Answer (score 1):

**test.txt**

```
with io.open('C:/test.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
for line in file:
    if x_1 in line:
        print('x_1      ' + line, end='')
    if x_2 in line:
        print('x_2      ' + line, end='')
    if x_3 in line:
        print('x_3      ' + line, end='')
    if x_4 in line:
        print('x_4      ' + line, end='')
    if x_5 in line:
        print('x_5      ' + line, end='')
    if x_6 in line:
        print('x_6      ' + line, end='')
    if x_7 in line:
        print('x_7      ' + line, end='')
    if x_8 in line:
        print('x_8      ' + line, end='')
    if x_9 in line:
        print('x_9      ' + line, end='')
    if x_10 in line:
        print('x_10      ' + line, end='')
x_4строка1
стрx_4ока2
строка3  x_4
```

**main.py**

```
import io

myList = ("x_1", "x_2", "x_3", "x_4", "x_5", "x_6", "x_7", "x_8", "x_9", "x_10", )

with io.open('test.txt') as file:

    for i in myList:
        for line in file:
            if i in line:
                print('{}      {}'.format(i, line), end='')

        file.seek(0)
```

---

**Результат:**

```
x_1          if x_1 in line:
x_1              print('x_1      ' + line, end='')
x_1          if x_10 in line:
x_1              print('x_10      ' + line, end='')
x_2          if x_2 in line:
x_2              print('x_2      ' + line, end='')
x_3          if x_3 in line:
x_3              print('x_3      ' + line, end='')
x_4          if x_4 in line:
x_4              print('x_4      ' + line, end='')
x_4      x_4строка1
x_4      стрx_4ока2
x_4      строка3  x_4
x_5          if x_5 in line:
x_5              print('x_5      ' + line, end='')
x_6          if x_6 in line:
x_6              print('x_6      ' + line, end='')
x_7          if x_7 in line:
x_7              print('x_7      ' + line, end='')
x_8          if x_8 in line:
x_8              print('x_8      ' + line, end='')
x_9          if x_9 in line:
x_9              print('x_9      ' + line, end='')
x_10          if x_10 in line:
x_10              print('x_10      ' + line, end='')
```